# Extracting a character that contains a certain type of element in R

Tags: r

For Example, lets say I have the following string

```
vec <- " @_Jim98 Did you turn off the stove @9am?"
```

I would like to count the number of @ characters that contain only numbers,letters,@, and underscore symbol in the string. In the case above, it would only count 1 since @9am? contains the ? symbol, so it won't be counted.

Also, it could not be longer than 10 characters.

Answer (score 3):

**1)** Search for @ followed by any number of the allowed characters `"\\w"` followed by a whitespace character `"\\s"` or `|` end of string `$`.  If zero word characters are allowable then change the + to *.  The expression is vectorized, i.e. `x` can be a character vector.  No packages are used.

```
x <- " @_Jim98 Did you turn off the stove @9am?" # test input

pat <- "@\\w+(\\s|$)"
lengths(regmatches(x, gregexpr(pat, x)))
## [1] 1
```

Note that the reason for `regmatches` is that `gregexpr` produces a -1 rather than a zero length vector for no matches whereas `regmatches` will produce a zero length vector.  Thus it works for the edge case of no matches.

**2)** A slightly more compact solution would be this where `pat` is from above:

```
library(gsubfn)
lengths(strapplyc(x, pat))
## [1] 1
```

Comment: it matches `@word@word` which might be ok if we follow strictly OP's description, but then `word@ ` (followed by blank) should be matched and it's not

Comment: The question did not specify all the rules.  I think it's likely that this does not occur and if it does the way it is handled may be the desired one.  We don't really know.

Comment: @Jan I'll choose an answer I'm just taking my time to test both solutions with my actual code and I'll see which one is more robust, weighted by style if it's a draw.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with a regular expression. I'm interpreting that you are counting words separated by space characters or occurring at the beginning or end of the string. This assumes the `@` is at the start of the word, and I match a `@` followed by some number of word characters `\\w`(letters and digits) or underscores. You can remove the first `(^|\\s)` if you don't care about having `@` at the beginning of the word and would like to count 3 words in, for example, `" @_Jim98 Did the Latin@s or tom@domain turn off the stove @9am?"`

```r
stringr::str_count(" @_Jim98 Did you turn off the stove @9am?", "(^|\\s)@(\\w|_)*?($|\\s)")
#> [1] 1
```

Created on 2018-04-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I think you don't need the beginning of the pattern: `(^|\\s)`

Comment: I took time to notice that your answer is actually what doesn't work with @G. Grothendieck  's solution